# Binding values with INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have run into a problem with binding values with a `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY` query in PDO. 
The error I'm getting is `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`.

The buildup of the SQL seems to be correct:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (user_name,user_id) 
  VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_name = ?,user_id = ?
```

Am I right in thinking that it needs binding the same values again to the parameters in the `foreach` loop for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause? Can anyone show me how to do that?

```
$update_fields .= $comma.$filter. " = ?";
$filters = array("user_name"=>"User Name","user_id"=>"User ID");
$field = "";
$comma = "";

foreach ($filters as $filter => $title) {
     $filterVar = "post_".$filter;             
     $$filterVar  = (isset($_POST["$filterVar"]) ? $_POST["$filterVar"] : "");

      if ($$filterVar) {    
          $fields .= $comma.$filter;
          $values .= $comma.$$filterVar;
          $update_fields .= $comma.$filter. " = ?";
          $comma = ",";
      }
}

$values_arr = explode(',',$values);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($values_arr) - 1) . '?'; 

$sql .= "INSERT INTO `mytable` ($fields) VALUES ($in)";
$sql .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $update_fields ";

$users = $dbh->prepare($sql);
print $sql; 
$i = 1;

foreach ($values_arr as $value) {   //  binding values
    $users->bindValue($i++, $value);
}

$users->execute($values_arr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that it will need to bind the same values for both parts. But I think if you are going to pass a values array to `execute`, you do not need to bind values beforehand, so you should be able to skip the `foreach...bindValue` part. This is like Example 3 in [the PHP docs on PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). However, since you have twice as many `?` placeholders because of the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part, your values array will need to be doubled as well. I think this should work.

```
$double_values = array_merge($values_arr, $values_arr);
$users->execute($double_values);
```